# Can I update a set of rows only if the updated row does not already exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables, `url` and `tweet`. `url` has the following structure:

```
 id | expanded_url | display_url | url
---------------------------------------
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between `url` and `tweet`, so there is a JOIN table (`urls_tweets`) that looks like this:

```
 id | tweet_id | url_id
------------------------
```

The problem is that there are duplicate entries in the `url` table -- unique indexes had not been used properly, and I am trying to clear out the duplicates so I can create those. I've run a query to find all the duplicate entries in the `url` table, and removing them is easy enough.

The problem now is that I need to update `urls_tweets` to point to the canonical record, since the duplicates are being deleted. Of course, in `urls_tweets`, `tweet_id` and `url_id` must be unique together. Running a simple query like the following fails because it will create records that violate the uniqueness constraints on `urls_tweets`:

```
UPDATE urls_tweets SET url_id = <primary url record id> WHERE url_id IN (<duplicate url record ids>);
```

Is there a way to update, or create or delete or whatever I have to do, to have records in `urls_tweets` point to the correct `url` record without having duplicate (`tweet_id`, `url_id`) pairs?

Comment: Four step process.  1) Disable relationships 2) update URL_Tweets to canonical record where url_tweet doesn't exist.  3) Then delete URL_tweets where parent record doesn't exist, 4) enable relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table `url_id_remap` that contains all the url_ids for duplicates, and the preferred canonical url_id. Populate this table as you do your deletions.

Then update your `urls_tweets` table using a JOIN:

```
UPDATE urls_tweets AS ut
JOIN url_id_remap AS r ON ut.url_id = r.duplicate_url_id
SET ut.url_id = r.canonical_url_id;
```

The `JOIN` naturally limits this to only rows that need to be changed, because it won't find any entry in `url_id_remap` that satisfies the join unless you've inserted a row for that url_id.